# What does System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(true) do?

Tags: c#, .net, assert

I found the following code in a console application, which seemed a bit strange:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(true);
```

What does it do?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. Presumably the original author meant to put something other than `true` there.

Comment: In a `DEBUG` build, the method call will do nothing. In a release build the method call will not even be compiled into the program.

Comment: Yes I do know that, I posted the question because it took a couple of brain cells to figure out why somebody would put such no-use statement in the code. Because of just that, I felt like I might as well post a question about it  and answer at the same time, but seems a lot of other people already had time to downvote the question.

Comment: @JimAho I've changed your title, because people seem to misunderstand the question

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Yes I think so too, thanks for the better title.

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer with the surrounding code. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): *"If the result is **false**, it sends a failure message to the Listeners collection."* Maybe in your case it served as a trace for a logical branch (at some point during development). But as already mentioned it doesn't serve any purpose now and should be removed.

Comment: It's really hard (impossible) to answer a `why` question. Perhaps you can ask the original coder? check source control to find out who added it and ask him/her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Gabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310574/gabe) it doesnt do much:

> In a DEBUG build, the method call will do nothing. In a release build
>   the method call will not even be compiled into the program.

Probably the code was left there by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like a canary test.**

A [canary test](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/02/canary-tests.html) is a simple test that's expected to always pass. It checks very basic things, like (in this case), "did all my frameworks load correctly?" If that assert ever *fails*, then the person who wrote it knows that they have a serious problem somewhere with their build process and there's no point in even looking at any other bugs until it's fixed.

While this may seem ridiculous, I've seen introductory unit testing & TDD courses that *explicitly* teach people to start with an Assert(true) canary test. It's possible that whoever put in that code was just doing it the way they were taught

Comment: I think it's doubtful that in the .Net framework, someone intelligent actually felt the need to verify that System.Diagnostics works.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is a "no-op" as written. It does nothing. It's like writing:

```
if (true) { }
```

Personally (and I think most would agree), I find no value in anything of this nature, and I think it only serves to clutter code. I have seen things like this and have some thought on why I think people do it though. Some programmers seem to use scripted patterns as a guide to such an extreme that meaningless garbage like this results. And some management seems to place so little trust in their employees that they actually demand rigid adherance to scripted patterns like this!

In the case of a no-op Assert like you have posted, it may be that someone had planned to make an actual assertion and forgot to fix it. But it may also be that someone involved in the development process had such a dependence on set patterns that they were unable to see the uselessness of this statement. They may just hold to the opinion that a Unit Test must always end with at least one Assert, even if there is nothing to assert.

And if so they are wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you just wait and read the comment on the Method you would already knew the answer
[image: a]

### Edit

as Pointed out in the comments section if the op wants to know why would somebody use this method I think is to debug something like, I want to debug if when I add 3 to 1 it will be four so I would use it like this

```
Debug.Assert(3+1 == 4);
```

if it is a four then everything is fine but if it is not four a message box like this will appear
[image: pic]
And that would have more useful information

Comment: I think the OP read the method documentation and couldn't understand why somebody would hardcode a no-op.